# How to write raw html inside a div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, json

Just wanted to wite a raw html inside a div after but some researching I'm confused.

Send a string from server to client with ajax(xhr) like:

```
"&lt;p&gt;123&lt;/p&gt;"
```

and put it inside a div with this:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    url: "/GetData",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: inputParams,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (msg) {

      //msg is &lt;p&gt;123&lt;/p&gt;
      $('#testdiv').html($.parseHTML(msg));

    },
    error: function (xhr) {

    }
});
```

but it does not show the result : 123 on my page it show:

```
<p>123</p>
```

I tested this commands but does not worked:

```
//msg is &lt;p&gt;123&lt;/p&gt;

$('#testdiv').html(msg));

$('#testdiv').html($.parseHTML(msg));
```

**Update:**
After some testing I found that if I send

```
 "&lt;p&gt;123&lt;/p&gt;"   the result will be  <p>123</p>
```

but if I send

```
 <p>123</p>   the result willl be ok I mean only 123
```

Comment: Try `$.parseHTML(msg)[0]`.

Comment: Why is the server sending encoded HTML instead of ordinary HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var msg = "&lt;b&gt;123&lt;/b&gt;";
$('#testdiv').html($('<textarea />').html(msg).text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testdiv"></div>
```

**Explanation:**

You tried to parse non-html string as html using `parseHTML`, and since the (non-html) string contained html entities, it was just decoded. We first had to decode the string to html friendly characters within the javascript, then parse the HTML.

```
$('<textarea />').html(msg).text()
```

This causes the `html()` of a new/temporary element (`<textarea/>`) without printing into any actual `DOM element`, causing jQuery to decode it into HTML, which is then used again with `.text()`.